# New folders made inside Flask static folder are not detected in Git control but new files are detected

Tags: git

I am making a simple flask app that requires a file `output.jpg` file in `static/images/` folder. After testing the app locally, I pushed to production, but the app kept timing out.

On further inspection, I came to realize that the app was looking for the file, but the parent folder `images/` was not present in `static/` or anywhere else. When I check the repo on GitHub, the folder is not present there. The folder is present locally. I tried renaming the folder and did a `git status` check and got clean working tree. I tried creating other folders with other names in the same `static` folder, but none of them showed up on `git status` check.

At the same location there is a `styles/` folder which is added to Git. Creating a folder in any subfolders in `static/`, including in `styles` makes them invisible to git. Interestingly, when a regular file is created in `static` and any subfolders in it, the file will show up in git as untracked. I can't figure out how to fix this because I don't know what is causing it.

My `.gitignore`:

```
*.vscode/
*.json
!*products.json
*.p
*.jpg
*.png
!overlay.png
*__pycache__/
.venv
randomimage.py
*.txt
*.log
*.checkpoint
instagram.py
```

Folder tree:

```sh
.
├── templates
│   └── index.html
├── static
│   ├── styles
│   │   └── index.css
│   ├── __pycache__
│   │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── images
├── server.py
├── __pycache__
│   ├── server.cpython-39.pyc
│   ├── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
│   └── dreambubble.cpython-39.pyc
├── __init__.py
├── dreambubble.py
└── data
    ├── temp.png
    ├── settings.p
    ├── __pycache__
    │   └── __init__.cpython-39.pyc
    ├── products.json
    ├── overlay.png
    ├── output.jpg
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── history.p
    └── chosen_product.p
```

Answer (score 1):

Git ignores empty folders. Since you have *.jpg in your .gitignore output.jpg is ignored, which renders static/images empty and so it is ignored as well. The real problem is ignoring jpg files while relying on git to deploy them.